# Web API endpoint without resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want my webapi endpoint to have a Get action without resource.

Ex: http://localhost:56155/ 
Resource: api/program/get, this action I want to hit when someone hit

http://localhost:56155/ in the browser.
Is that possible?

I added this in webapiconfig.cs

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
     name: "DefaultApi", 
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
     defaults: new { controller = "Program", 
                     action = "Get", 
                     id = RouteParameter.Optional 
     } 
);`
```

But it does not redirect or hit the action Get of my Program controller when I launch the app.

Comment: Your project launch config is probably wrong

Comment: Are you using Asp.Net Core or Asp.Net (on .Net Framework?). If you are using ASP.Net Core you can use a very small custom middleware to achieve this.

Comment: @Dan I am using .net framework 4.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mandatory segment **api** in your routeTemplate `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`. Just remove this segment and the route will work with the empty url
`routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"`.